# Dart html descendant selector not working as expected

Tags: html, css, dart

I want to select descendants of an element but I am unable to do so.
Trying the same through in a JS console works as expected with syntax `$$('.verse.v9 .content')`

There is the sample code in dart.

```dart
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

String html = '''
  <span class="verse v9">
        <span class="label">9</span>
        <span class="content">This is direct child </span>
        <span class="wj">
                <span class="content">This is grand child</span>
        </span>
</span>
''';

void main() {
  final document = parse(html);

  document.documentElement!
      .querySelectorAll('.verse.v9 > .content')
      .forEach((element) {
    print(element.innerHtml); // this prints direct child `This is direct child`
  });

  document.documentElement!
      .querySelectorAll('.verse.v9 .content')
      .forEach((element) {
    // this doesn't print anything I expect it to print
    // `This is direct child` and `This is grand child`
    print(element.innerHtml);
  });
}
```

JS fiddle to try it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/kv14f0db/

Comment: Could be a bug in package:html.  Have you checked the issues?

Comment: This could be the same issue.  There's a pull request that fixes it, but the contributor hasn't finished the google paperwork yet: https://github.com/dart-lang/html/issues/157

Comment: Thanks, Randal, it's looks like it is happing because of the same issue.